# Present view controller from UITabBarController without tab bar showing

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have read multiple answers regarding this issue. The main thing indicated is to set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed to true, which i have done and is still not working for me.

So this is my storyboard layout.

[image]

So i present a TableViewController from my TabBarController, the view i present is the bottom left on the storyboard. With hidesBottomBarWhenPushed set to true, i expect the bottom bar to be hidden but this is not the case. It actually adds a new bottom bar and upon navigating back to the tab view a new tab bar is overlapping the original one. You can see this in the screenshots below.

So firstly the tab bar, we then select the filter icon on the top right, which triggers the segue to the next controller.

[image]

So now the next controller loads in. As you can see the tab bar is displayed even though i have set hidesBottomBarWhenPushed on the storyboard.

[image]

And now when we navigate back there is a new tab bar overlapping the original.

[image]

I don't have much experience with tab bar controllers, have i done something wrong with my storyboard hierarchy maybe. Perhaps each tab should have its own navigation controller. However my tab bar also needs a navigation controller.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` of tableVC

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = true
```

In `viewWillAppear` of the VC before the tableVC

```
self.tabBarController?.tabBar.isHidden = false
```

Comment: I still get an extra bar overlapping, its as though another tab bar is being added on the segue.